# Filter different number of rows per group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I want to filter `x` rows per `id`, but the `x` differs for each `id`.

example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c('P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 
   'P2', 'P3', 'P3'),
           points = c(56, 94, 17, 57, 55, 15, 37, 44, 55, 32))
```

The data and below code is adapted from [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/07/select-the-first-row-by-group-in-r/).

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% c(1, 2))
```

This filters the first two rows for each id. So far so good.

But I want to filter **different** number of rows for each id based on the values stored in a vector like below

```
nrowtofilter <- c(3, 2, 1)
```

Thus, I want to filter 3 rows for `P1`, 2 for `P2`, and 1 for `P3`.

But when I do

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% nrowtofilter)
```

I extract the first 3 rows of each ID.

How can I filter `id`s based on `nrowtofilter`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A different approach with `cur_group_id`, which doesn't require breaking the dataset into a list of dataframes:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(row_number() <= nrowtofilter[cur_group_id()])

#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>   id    points
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 P1        56
#> 2 P1        94
#> 3 P1        17
#> 4 P2        55
#> 5 P2        15
#> 6 P3        55
```

Answer (score 2):

You could `split` the groups, and use `map2` (or `mapply`) to `slice` the first rows over groups and n:

```r
library(dplyr)
nrowtofilter <- c(3, 2, 1)
df %>% 
  group_split(id) %>% 
  map2(nrowtofilter, ~ slice_head(.x, n = .y)) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  id    points
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 P1        56
2 P1        94
3 P1        17
4 P2        55
5 P2        15
6 P3        55
```

---

In base R, with the same logic:

```r
split(df, df$id) |>
  Map(f = function(x, y) head(x, y), y = nrowtofilter) |>
  do.call(what = "rbind")
```

Answer (score 2):

First create a lookup table:

```r
nrowtofilter <- setNames(c(3, 2, 1), c('P1', 'P2', 'P3'))
# P1 P2 P3 
#  3  2  1
```

then `group_modify()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  group_modify(~ slice_head(.x, n = nrowtofilter[.y$id])) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 × 2
#   id    points
#   <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 P1        56
# 2 P1        94
# 3 P1        17
# 4 P2        55
# 5 P2        15
# 6 P3        55
```

where `.x` refers to the subset of rows for the given group, and `.y` a one-row tibble with one column per grouping variable that identifies the group.

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(id = unique(df$id), nrowtofilter) %>% 
  left_join(df, .) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= first(nrowtofilter), .by = 'id') %>% 
  select(-nrowtofilter)
```

-output

```
  id points
1 P1     56
2 P1     94
3 P1     17
4 P2     55
5 P2     15
6 P3     55
```